# MySql doesn't show up on my screen

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql version5.6 ,but when I enter the dos windows, and input the command lines below:

```
C:\Windows\system32>f:

F:\>cd F:\mysql\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

F:\mysql\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld.exe
```

the warning message is:

> 2015-03-08 20:47:46 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value
>   is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server
>   option (see documentation for more details).

I have taken methods on the internet, such as adding the line `defaults_for_timestamp=true`, but none works.

I have reinstalled it many times, but it just don't work. My system is Windows 8.1-64bit.

When I search the TaskManager there is a process named `mysqld.exe` but nothing happens on the screen.

Comment: I'd say that is a _warning_, not an _error_. MySQL will not refuse to start because of this. There must be another reason. Or: you sure it is _not_ started? Also: it says: "see documentation for more details" - what did that reveal?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I search the Task Manager,and find the "mysqld.exe", it does start. But on the dos window,,it just shows the Warning message and then nothing.so what should do next?

Comment: "and then nothing"... well, mysql is a daemon, so it _should not do anything visible there_. You are meant to connect to the running daemon using a client, typically via network. That is how such servers work. It is nothing that gives you a GUI or some other form of direct interaction thing. you start it once (typpically after booting the system or after chaning its configuration) and then it runs in background without ever being touched directly. It just waits for clients to connect and make queries for which it delivers the results. So you need a client or an application using a client.

Comment: @arkascha that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Hiya @ArinImmo I have edited your question a little. For one I tried to highlight the error-messages by putting it into a quote-block. Additionally I have stressed inline code and added in the information you gave in your comment. Please do not use comments to provide further information, but instead edit your own question, Thanks!

Comment: @Vogel612 OK, if you insist :-)

Comment: After the warning message pops, the dos window  blocks up  and I can't input any command then .In addtion, I can't find the client terminal of this version 5.6.

Comment: You are not meant to start the daemon that way. It is meant to be controlled via daemon control scripts. Might be called something like "service control" or similar under MS-Windows systems, not sure. You do not need a client matching a specific version. `sql` is a standard, so any client speaking that standard can be used. OK, taht is a bit simplified, but points into the right direction. Compare it to a http server ("web server") and a browser as a client. You can use _any_ browser to interact with _any_ http server, at least any reasonable modern one.

Comment: @ Vogel612 ,@arkascha,Wow,thanks for all you have done for me and this site.

Comment: You are welcome! One day you will help others here!

Comment: @arkascha, my English is not so good,if  I have made any mistake,please be tolerant. Yeah ,I know what you mean ,but the problem is I can't find the client and start it,let alone  input corresponding commands to make subsequent manipulations.

Comment: OK, sure,all fine. You did not do any mistake, not at all! Now the question is: what do you want to use a mysql server for? Usually people have an application the want to use which _requires_ a sql server to be available. But that does not seem to be the case for you. So: _what do you want to do_?

Comment: If you "just want to look around and get an idea", then maybe the "mysql workbench" is a good starting point. But note that such clients are development tools, not software meant for normal users in daily tasks. So things might be a little confusing at first.

Comment: haha. for example,err....., I only want to create a   temporary database and a table in the database to test something  ,not as a server   ,what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

> When I search the TaskManager there is a process named mysqld.exe but
>   nothing happens on the screen...

Well, mysql is a daemon, so it should not do anything visible on the screen.

You are meant to connect to the running daemon using a client, typically via network. That is how such servers work. It is nothing that gives you a GUI or some other form of direct interaction thing.

You start it once (typically after booting the system or after changing its configuration) and then it runs in background without ever being touched directly. It just waits for clients to connect and make queries for which it delivers the results. So you need a client or an application using a client to interact with it, to use it.